How to escape $ in Byteman?
I want to print a field whose name start with $ with Byteman, e.g. there's a
class Foo {
  public static int $5;
}

My problem is that Byteman interprets $ in leading position for its own purposes, as arguments or locals, so on
DO traceln(Foo.$5)

Byteman throws an
org.jboss.byteman.rule.exception.ParseException: rule  ...
Illegal character <$>

I've looked a bit at the manual, but I see no obvious way to escape it. I tried $$5 and \$5 but neither works. So how do you escape $ in Byteman?

I also tried to get it through reflection but that couldn't fetch the value, just the Field object
DO traceln(Foo.class.getField("$5"))

is successful, but
DO traceln(Foo.class.getField("$5").get(null))

throws
org.jboss.byteman.rule.exception.ExecuteException: MethodExpression.interpret : exception invoking method get file ...

The Field is public, so I'm not sure what's going on there...

Well, I was able to get it with jdb's print, so at least there's that workaround.

I worked around the reflection exception in the meantime. Some issue with different classloaders. But still, the Q remains, is there no way to access $ prefixed vars from Byteman, without reflection?
